# How should I use Geocoordinate.VerticalAccuracy to improve the Altitude value?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

I'm building a ride tracking app that includes making a note of your elevation gain (I'm really interested in when the user is going down hill, nor in their actual hight above sea level, but how often they were going up hill, and the overall distance).

However, on a sample ride I noticed that my elevation gain was quite significant, and more than the gentle hill I was on should really show.

I know the `Geocoordinate` class has a `VerticalAccuracy` class that gives me an estimate of how accurate (in metres) the Altitude property is.

My question is: Should I simply use the value as a threshold, where if the number is too high I should just consider the Altitude as spurious, or is there some (not too intensive (i.e. no Monte Carlo solutions here please)) calculation I can do with accuracy to take a reasonable guess based on the last (few) readings?